# Ударение в имени Элон

Tags: орфоэпия

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно читается имя Элон? Где ставить ударение?

Answer (score 1):

Мужское имя Элон довольно редкое,но обратимся к известному человеку с таким именем . **Википедия:**  Элон Маск (полное имя Илон Рив Маск) (**англ. Elon Reeve Musk /ˈiːlɒn ˈmʌsk/;** род. 28 июня 1971 года в Претории, ЮАР) — канадско-американский инженер, предприниматель, изобретатель и инвестор; миллиардер.

Как видим, ударение здесь имеется в транскрипции - на первый слог

Comment: Людмила, разрешите Вас исправить:  На ударение указывает штрих перед звуком i 
Двоеточие указывает на то, что звук i долгий

Comment: Да, верно, спасибо, просто долгий звук ведь обычно ударный?

Comment: Маска зовут Илон, окуда взялся Элон?

Comment: Здесь правильнее спросить, откуда взялся Маск.

Comment: М_Г , пишут и так, и так. Произносится i, а транслитерация - э. Автомобильные компании все пишут через э. Вопрос в другом: какое, чьё имя имела в виду автор вопроса.

Answer (score 0):

Если имя пишется на русском Элон, то ударение может стоять таким, где привычнее русскому слуху. Все равно это не английское имя, "английское" было бы "Илон" - с очевидным первым ударным гласным.

А касательно других носителей имени Элон или фамилии - это надо к специалистам по ивриту и Библии, Элон - имя одного из малозначительных персонажей библейских текстов. Мне кажется, там именно "Эл**о**н" правильно, но я иврита не знаю.

Нечто аналогично произошло с именем Альфред. Оно допускает два ударения - иногда в зависимости от времени жизни носителя.

....

Да, так и есть.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menachem_Elon
Слушать фонограмму. Хотя понятие ударения в иврите отличается от русского, ударение скорее на последний слог.

Answer (score 0):

Единственное имя, написанное по-русски как Элон, принадлежит библейскому персонажу и в оригинале (на иврите) произносится как Эйлон (с ударением на втором слоге), все остальные случаи - это фамилия Элон, известная в Израиле. Она тоже произносится с ударением на втором слоге. Есть еще ивритское имя Алон (в английском написании Alon), возможно кому-то кажется, что Alon звучит как Элон.

Во всех вариантах ударение падает на второй слог.

Comment: *как Эйлон* - а кто дает именно такую транскрипцию, с дифтонгом или йодом? ***אֵילֹן*** Мне кажется дифтонг нехарактерен для иврита, а йод там, похоже, не должен читаться после алефа.

Comment: Дифтонги не характерны для иврита, но под первой буквой (алеф) стоит огласовка "э", а под второй (йод) стоит шва нах (у вас не показан) - получается Й. Итого: Эй.

Comment: Но я взял написание в английской вике, так нет шва под йодом. Если бы было, вопросов бы не было... И здесь её нету... https://www.studylight.org/lexicons/hebrew/356.html  ладно, ьне принципиально. Я думал есть авторитетный источник с такой транскртпцией. ... Хотя погодите... "Шва нах"  на произношение вообще не влияет. Я спутал.

Comment: Возьмите известный курортный город Эйлат. Те же огласовки под алефом и йодом, а произношение ни у кого сомнения не вызывает.

Comment: Я спрашивал про авторитетный источник, аналогия таковым не является. Я правтльно понял, что транскрипция Эйлон - ваше личная инициатива?

Comment: Не моя инициатива, а факт. Возможно, мне удастся найти источник, который вас убедит, возможно, нет, но это не отменяет самого факта. Пока могу сослаться на известное мне правило, что в иврите нет "молчащих" букв (за редкими исключениями) и на носителей языка, которые все произносят в своих молитвах то самое библейское имя именно как Эйлон . Однако, этот спор выходит за рамки проблем русского языка, не так ли?

Comment: Факта тут нет и быть не может. Речь идет о написании библейского имени и изменение произношения, зафиксированного каноническим текстом (Судьи 12:11), как минимум странно. Или кто-то до вас написал и обосновал. Да, за рамки русского выходит. Но ссылку-то, если она есть дать можно.

Comment: @Мимоходов. Не знаю убедит ли вас живая речь: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4y9nPdjLYRs, 16:57 - 17:05) Ясно слышится дважды "Эйл**о**н а-Звулан**и**" (В русском варианте Елон Завулонянин (Судьи 12:11 и 12:12)

Comment: ***Елон** Завулонянин* - вот это убеждает.  В том, что ссылки у вас нет. Накпомню вопрос: *а кто дает именно такую транскрипцию, с дифтонгом или йодом?* Ответ: никто. А слушать можно очень долго. Но я не специалист по ивриту, на мой вкус там йода нету.

Comment: (1) Ссылок на Книгу судей на русском много, вот например: https://www.bible-center.ru/ru/bibletext/jud/12  Везде Елон (2) Перед вами есть ивритское слово אֵילֹן с огласовками. Вопрос о том, умеете ли вы читать огласованный текст на иврите.